# Aurelia bundle custom components

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have created a SPA using Aurelia with typescript and WebApi. I want to bundle everything using `aurelia-cli` in order to minimize request in order to increase access performance. I have the following configuration:

```
var aurelia = require("aurelia-cli");

var bundleConfig = {
    js: {
        "Scripts/aurelia-bundle": {
            modules: [ 
                "github:aurelia/*",
                "Components/**/*.js"
            ],
            options: {
                inject: true,
                minify: true
            }
        }
    },
    template: {
        "Scripts/aurelia-bundle": {
            pattern: "Components/**/*.html",
            options: {
                inject: true
            }
        }
    }
};

aurelia.command("bundle", bundleConfig);
```

A basic componenet would be:

```
import {bindable, inject} from "aurelia-framework";

export class Home {

    // Custom properties

    constructor() {
      // Implementation
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

All my `views` and `viewmodels` are located inside the `Components`. If I remove `"Components/**/*.js"` from the module imports, the bundle completes, and it generates the bundled js file. If I let that line there I get the following error:

```
info: Creating bundle ...

err  Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Work\aurelia-framework.js'
         at Error (native) C:\Work\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\builder.js:23
  throw new Error('Unhandled promise rejection.\n' + reason && reason.stack ||
        ^
Error: Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Work\aurelia-framework.js'
    at Error (native)
    at C:\Work\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\builder.js:23:9
    at Object.lib$rsvp$events$$default.trigger (C:\Work\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:245:13)
    at null._onTimeout (C:\Work\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:779:47)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:119:15)
```

I guess the problem is that the `aurelia-cli` can't see `aurelia-framework` import from the `typescript` file, but it compiles and transpiles perfectly.

So my question is how can I include my custom components into the bundle?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/06/23/bundling-an-aurelia-application/#importantnoteswhenbundlingjs)

Comment: This is not a problem. I tried putting empty `typescript` files in subdirectories within the `Components` folder and the bundle command works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not including `aurelia-framework` and `aurelia-router` in the `package.json` and the resulting `config.js` file generated didn't know at bundle time what `import {inject} from "aurelia-framework"` meant. So I added these line to the `package.json`:

```
"aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@0.15.0",
"aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router@0.11.0"
```

and when I ran `aurelia bundle --force` it bundled successfully.

Unfortunately, `aurelia-cli` [will go obsolete](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/164) in favor of another bundling tool (yeei).